# Is it possible to assign long long returne value to int64_t without losing the precision in a 64-bit Machine?

Tags: c++, c

I have implemented below code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<sys/types.h>
main()
{
    int64_t i64value1 = 0;
    int64_t i64value2 = 0;
    long long llvalue = 0;
    const char *s = "10811535359";
    i64value1 = atoll(s);
    llvalue = atoll(s);
    i64value2 = llvalue;
    printf("s : [%s]\n",s);
    printf("i64value1 : [%d]\n",i64value1);
    printf("llvalue : [%lld]\n",llvalue);
    printf("i64value2 : [%d]\n",i64value2);
}
```

Output of the above progrom is :

```
s : [10811535359]
i64value1 : [-2073366529]
llvalue : [10811535359]
i64value2 : [-2073366529]
```

The compiler used is :

```
 gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
```

The OS is *x86_64 GNU/Linux 2.6.18-194*

Since *long long* is a signed 64-bit integer and is, for all intents and purposes, identical to *int64_t* type, logically *int64_t* and *long long* should be equivalent types. And some places mention to use *int64_t* instead of *long long*.
But when I look at *stdint.h*, it tells me why I see the above behavior:

```
# if __WORDSIZE == 64 
typedef long int  int64_t; 
# else 
__extension__ 
typedef long long int  int64_t; 
# endif
```

In a 64-bit compile, *int64_t* is *long int*, not a *long long int*.

My Question is, Is there a workaround/solution to assign long long returned value to int64_t without losing the precision in 64 bit Machine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `long` and `long long` are the same on x86_64. `int64_t` is a type that has exactly 64 bits whereas `long long` is _at least_ as large as `long`, and `long` is _at least_ as large as `int` (and, incidentially 64 bits, too, in this case). Insofar, no worries.

Comment: This is true if by x86_64 you mean *Linux* x86-64. It is definitely not true for 64-bit Windows on the same hardware (where `long` is 32-bits).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loss does not happen in the conversions but in the printing:

```
printf("i64value1 : [%d]\n",i64value1);
```

The `int64_t` argument is accessed as if it were an `int`. This is undefined behaviour, but usually the low 32 bits are sign extended.

Proper compiler warnings (such as gcc `-Wformat`) should complain about this.

Answer (score 2):

Jilles is right.

Either use `std::cout <<` which I believe should handle it the right way, or using `printf("i64value2 : [%lld]\n",i64value2);` while printing should solve it.

There're also [format macros for fixed-width integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) that will handle the situation correctly regardless of typedef of `int64_t`. There're alternatives even for `int_fast32_t` which would otherwise be very ugly to handle.

In this case it would be:

```cpp
#include <cinttypes>

printf("\tvalue is %" PRId64 "\n", i64value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) - `long long` is the same as `long` which is to say a 64bit value. There is no precision loss in this case.